# How to alternate speed using an array of integers for javax swing timer

Tags: java, random, timer

I am attempting to simulate rain falling using fixed line lengths with randomly generated x coordinates. I have got the random x coordinates working but I want lines to have different falling speeds as well once they are repainted onto the window. I am using the javax swing timer and the java Random to generate integers to pass into my "speed" array as indexes. The speed however does not change. It remains the same and is way too fast.

```
public class rain extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
int i = 0;
int[] speed = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};
double[] x = {10, 202, 330, 140, 250, 160, 470, 180, 290, 510};
double y1 = 10, y2 = 20;
double down = 1;
Random random = new Random();
//Timer t = new Timer(speed[i], this);



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D l = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(x[i], y1, x[i], y2);
        l.setColor(Color.blue);
        l.draw(line);
        Timer t = new Timer(speed[i], this);
        t.start();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
        if (y2 < 380) {
            y1 += down; 
            y2 += down;
        }else{
            y1 = 10;
            y2 = 20;
            i = random.nextInt(10);

        }
    repaint();

}
```

Comment: I think your problem is with the variable i. From looking at the code spped[i] will not see the change you do to i in actionPerformed, therefore i will just be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a new Timer each time your panel is repainted, and all the previous ones are still running. You should change your algorithm to use a unique timer, and compute the new y based on the previous one and on the current speed.

For example, the time would repaint every 40 milliseconds. If the speed is N, the new y would be the previous one + `(N * down)`